Publish .NET Core 8 runtime in VS2022?
I last built a C# application with VS2022 using .NET 6.0. When I publish this as a portable app, I get the runtimes included under the "publish" directory. This enables me to install the app on any system that doesn't already include the .NET 6.0 runtime. I just tested this with the same VS2022 version I am using for my .NET 8 app.
I have just built a C# app using .NET 8.0 with the latest VS2022, but when I publish it, there is no runtime included under the publish directory. I have looked online but can't see anything that explains this.
Am I missing something about publishing the .NET 8 runtime, or has there been some change that means the .NET 8 runtime is no longer publishable? (or am I totally clueless about something else?)
Note that by "publish", I mean the Publish command in the Build menu.

Update 1
After Melroy's comment I did see that I had the "Deployment Mode" set to "Framework Dependent". When I set it to "Self-Contained", I got a whole bunch of MS DLLs in my publish directory. However compared to .NET 6.0, I see for .NET 8.0:

There is no longer a "runtime" directory under the publish directory.

There are about 185 DLLs (and 1 application "createdump") included in the publish directory, whereas for .NET 6.0, I only had about 15 DLLs added by publishing.


I went back to my previous .NET 6.0 version program and converted this from .NET 6.0 to .NET 8.0. This program only reads and writes simple CSV files from local directories. The publish directory went from the approximately additional 15 windows/net DLLs to 185+ DLLs. It now includes things like cryptography, network and web resources. The only way that this could make sense to me is bloat in the .NET 8.0
These extra DLLs have me questioning: am I correctly publishing these apps?
Update 2
Using my previous .Net 6.0 application as an example.  These are the files that are in the publish directory (minus my actual application files):
    blah\blah\Publish\
        |   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll
        |   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll
        |   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions.dll
        |   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.dll
        |   Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions.dll
        |   Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.dll
        |   Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.dll
        |   Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll
        |   Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream.dll
        |   Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.dll
        |   System.Drawing.Common.dll
        |   System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.dll
        |   System.Xml.XPath.XmlDocument.dll
        |   
        \---runtimes
            +---unix
            |   \---lib
            |       \---netcoreapp3.0
            |               System.Drawing.Common.dll
            |               
            \---win
                \---lib
                    \---netcoreapp3.0
                            Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.dll
                            System.Drawing.Common.dll
                            System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.dll

When I make the single change from .Net 6.0 to .Net 8.0 and re-publish the application, these are the published files (Note that they are all in the same directory, and that there are no sub-directories):
Blah\Blah\Publish\
    clretwrc.dll
    clrgc.dll
    clrjit.dll
    coreclr.dll
    createdump.exe
    hostfxr.dll
    hostpolicy.dll
    Microsoft.CSharp.dll
    Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.x86.dll
    Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll
    Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll
    Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions.dll
    Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.dll
    Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions.dll
    Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.dll
    Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.dll
    Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll
    Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream.dll
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.dll
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
    Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll
    Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll
    Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.dll
    mscordaccore.dll
    mscordaccore_x86_x86_8.0.324.11423.dll
    mscordbi.dll
    mscorlib.dll
    mscorrc.dll
    msquic.dll
    netstandard.dll
    System.AppContext.dll
    System.Buffers.dll
    System.Collections.Concurrent.dll
    System.Collections.dll
    System.Collections.Immutable.dll
    System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll
    System.Collections.Specialized.dll
    System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll
    System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll
    System.ComponentModel.dll
    System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll
    System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll
    System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll
    System.Configuration.dll
    System.Console.dll
    System.Core.dll
    System.Data.Common.dll
    System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
    System.Data.dll
    System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll
    System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll
    System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll
    System.Diagnostics.Process.dll
    System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll
    System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener.dll
    System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll
    System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll
    System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll
    System.dll
    System.Drawing.Common.dll
    System.Drawing.dll
    System.Drawing.Primitives.dll
    System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll
    System.Formats.Asn1.dll
    System.Formats.Tar.dll
    System.Globalization.Calendars.dll
    System.Globalization.dll
    System.Globalization.Extensions.dll
    System.IO.Compression.Brotli.dll
    System.IO.Compression.dll
    System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll
    System.IO.Compression.Native.dll
    System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll
    System.IO.dll
    System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl.dll
    System.IO.FileSystem.dll
    System.IO.FileSystem.DriveInfo.dll
    System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll
    System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.dll
    System.IO.IsolatedStorage.dll
    System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll
    System.IO.Pipes.AccessControl.dll
    System.IO.Pipes.dll
    System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream.dll
    System.Linq.dll
    System.Linq.Expressions.dll
    System.Linq.Parallel.dll
    System.Linq.Queryable.dll
    System.Memory.dll
    System.Net.dll
    System.Net.Http.dll
    System.Net.Http.Json.dll
    System.Net.HttpListener.dll
    System.Net.Mail.dll
    System.Net.NameResolution.dll
    System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll
    System.Net.Ping.dll
    System.Net.Primitives.dll
    System.Net.Quic.dll
    System.Net.Requests.dll
    System.Net.Security.dll
    System.Net.ServicePoint.dll
    System.Net.Sockets.dll
    System.Net.WebClient.dll
    System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.dll
    System.Net.WebProxy.dll
    System.Net.WebSockets.Client.dll
    System.Net.WebSockets.dll
    System.Numerics.dll
    System.Numerics.Vectors.dll
    System.ObjectModel.dll
    System.Private.CoreLib.dll
    System.Private.DataContractSerialization.dll
    System.Private.Uri.dll
    System.Private.Xml.dll
    System.Private.Xml.Linq.dll
    System.Reflection.DispatchProxy.dll
    System.Reflection.dll
    System.Reflection.Emit.dll
    System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll
    System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll
    System.Reflection.Extensions.dll
    System.Reflection.Metadata.dll
    System.Reflection.Primitives.dll
    System.Reflection.TypeExtensions.dll
    System.Resources.Reader.dll
    System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll
    System.Resources.Writer.dll
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll
    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.VisualC.dll
    System.Runtime.dll
    System.Runtime.Extensions.dll
    System.Runtime.Handles.dll
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.dll
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll
    System.Runtime.Intrinsics.dll
    System.Runtime.Loader.dll
    System.Runtime.Numerics.dll
    System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
    System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll
    System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll
    System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll
    System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll
    System.Security.AccessControl.dll
    System.Security.Claims.dll
    System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll
    System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll
    System.Security.Cryptography.Csp.dll
    System.Security.Cryptography.dll
    System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll
    System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl.dll
    System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.dll
    System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll
    System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll
    System.Security.dll
    System.Security.Principal.dll
    System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll
    System.Security.SecureString.dll
    System.ServiceModel.Web.dll
    System.ServiceProcess.dll
    System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll
    System.Text.Encoding.dll
    System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll
    System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll
    System.Text.Json.dll
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll
    System.Threading.Channels.dll
    System.Threading.dll
    System.Threading.Overlapped.dll
    System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll
    System.Threading.Tasks.dll
    System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll
    System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll
    System.Threading.Thread.dll
    System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll
    System.Threading.Timer.dll
    System.Transactions.dll
    System.Transactions.Local.dll
    System.ValueTuple.dll
    System.Web.dll
    System.Web.HttpUtility.dll
    System.Windows.dll
    System.Xml.dll
    System.Xml.Linq.dll
    System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll
    System.Xml.Serialization.dll
    System.Xml.XDocument.dll
    System.Xml.XmlDocument.dll
    System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll
    System.Xml.XPath.dll
    System.Xml.XPath.XDocument.dll
    System.Xml.XPath.XmlDocument.dll
    WindowsBase.dll

The reason all of this concerns me is that the next step is to build an installer for my new application, and that installer should only include the files that are actually needed.

When you published was the "Deployment Mode" set to Self-Contained or Framework Dependent? I just set it to self -contained and now it shows me all the libraries that I was using with the project I just published. I also had to choose the platform I was publishing for, in my case it was win-x64. This link should help understand all the publishing options - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/

@MelroyCoelho  OK.  It was originally set to "Framework Dependent".  But when set to "Self-Contained", I get my projects components in the publish dir, but there is no "runtime" dir that I see with 6.0.  Also I get about 185 dlls (and a "createdump" application!) compared to the maybe 15  dlls with my v6.0 other app.    There are a whole bunch of things that list that do not make sense to me based on what the applications are doing (basically simple processing of CSV files)

@MelroyCoelho I just converted my previous v6.0 app to v8.0, and it is producing the same publish behavior.  So there seems to be a change in between 6.0 and 8.0 wrt publishing.
